# Rails: Form_for fields without corresponding database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do up a rails form_for that includes a checkbox for `:terms_and_conditions` (with `validates_presence_of`). `terms_and_conditions` has not been declared as a column in the corresponding database table.

At the moment, when I submit the form and try to create a new model with `MyModel.new(params[:mymodel])`, I get an *'unknown attribute: terms_and_conditions'* error.

So, just wondering: how do I run create a field for a column - and run validations on it - without inserting that field into the database?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a virtual attribute for terms_and_conditions in your model.
Take a look at this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes)

Comment: Ach - many thanks. Knew it was something like that - I was forgetting to include a setter method.

Answer (score 3):

For accepting T&Cs only, you should now be able to just put this in your model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms_and_conditions
```